# Office 365 unified API error when deleting a calendar

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365api

Today I was playing with the new (beta) Office 365 unified APIs and I noticed a very strange behaviour, possibly a bug on Microsoft side.

When I try to delete a calendar using the unified APIs I get a 409 error, the same I get when I try to create a new calendar passing a name which already exists. Here below the REST details.

Request:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendars/AAMkAGZlO...6AAA= HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ...
Host: graph.microsoft.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
{"error":{"code":"ErrorFolderExists","message":"A folder with the specified name already exists."}}
```

According to the specs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#Deletecalendars), 204 should be returned.

Is there a way to create a bug on Microsoft side, such as a bug tracker?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Thanks for the report! I'd like to try to reproduce this so our team can investigate. To clarify, do you have a folder by the same name already in your deleted items folder?

Comment: Hi Jason, I didn't notice this but yes you are right. This happens when a calendar with the same name was already deleted. 
Also the update use case fails exactly like the delete. If I try to rename a folder using a name of a folder which existed but was deleted, 409 is returned.

Comment: Thanks! I can reproduce this even with the non-unified endpoint. I've filed a bug with our engineering team to investigate.

Comment: @JasonJohnston when this have any update, please tell us. Do somebody know any workaround?

Comment: Well, I found you can rename the calendar and then delete it. But then this name is also "poisoned" so if you create a new calendar with the new name you can't delete it.

Comment: @JasonJohnston any update on this? still facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, this is still an issue. For the time being you can work around this by catching the error, renaming the folder, then retrying the delete. For example if the folder/calendar is named `Test`, you could rename to `Test (1)`.

Comment: @JasonJohnston, can you confirm if this issue is still going on?

Comment: Still an issue in 2018

Comment: And still in May 2020.

Answer (score 0):

This has been Service Exception processing request. 
Code: ErrorFolderExists, 
Message: A folder with the specified name already exists., Retry
The reason for this error, is that the source platform has a native folder - 'Notes' for example, and the destination Exchange / Outlook also has a native Notes folder, but only for Outlook Notes.

Solution

Therefore the source folder needs to be renamed for a migration to work.